# Address COM in OS X via FireMonkey/C++

Tags: c++, macos, com, c++builder, firemonkey

The COM-based Blackmagic DeckLink API is available for both Windows and OS X. I wish to address it in OS X but using FireMonkey (FMX) in C++. The problem is that their sample code* is written for Cocoa and I have no idea how to rewrite it for FireMonkey. Does anyone have any experience with this, is it even possible.

Or, is there a generic way in which libraries with a COM interface can be addressed in FireMonkey/OS X?

Here's part of the code for Cocoa, per request.

```
void    InitDeckLinkAPI (void)
{
    CFURLRef        bundleURL;

    bundleURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR(kDeckLinkAPI_BundlePath), kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, true);
    if (bundleURL != NULL)
    {
        gDeckLinkAPIBundleRef = CFBundleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, bundleURL);
        if (gDeckLinkAPIBundleRef != NULL)
        {
            gCreateIteratorFunc = (CreateIteratorFunc)CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(gDeckLinkAPIBundleRef, CFSTR("CreateDeckLinkIteratorInstance_0002"));
            gCreateAPIInformationFunc = (CreateAPIInformationFunc)CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(gDeckLinkAPIBundleRef, CFSTR("CreateDeckLinkAPIInformationInstance_0001"));
            gCreateOpenGLPreviewFunc = (CreateOpenGLScreenPreviewHelperFunc)CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(gDeckLinkAPIBundleRef, CFSTR("CreateOpenGLScreenPreviewHelper_0001"));
            gCreateCocoaPreviewFunc = (CreateCocoaScreenPreviewFunc)CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(gDeckLinkAPIBundleRef, CFSTR("CreateCocoaScreenPreview_0001"));
            gCreateVideoConversionFunc = (CreateVideoConversionInstanceFunc)CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(gDeckLinkAPIBundleRef, CFSTR("CreateVideoConversionInstance_0001"));
        }
        CFRelease(bundleURL);
    }
}

bool        IsDeckLinkAPIPresent (void)
{
    // If the DeckLink API bundle was successfully loaded, return this knowledge to the caller
    if (gDeckLinkAPIBundleRef != NULL)
        return true;

    return false;
}

IDeckLinkIterator*      CreateDeckLinkIteratorInstance (void)
{
    pthread_once(&gDeckLinkOnceControl, InitDeckLinkAPI);

    if (gCreateIteratorFunc == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return gCreateIteratorFunc();
}
```

*Too long to include here but you can download it [here](http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/support/sdks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On platforms without native COM support (such as OS X) a C entry point should be provided to access an Interface and in DeckLink API there is such factory methods :

```
IDeckLinkIterator *deckLinkIterator = CreateDeckLinkIteratorInstance();
```

Thus you can simply use DeckLink API in C++Builder. But there is a problem, C++Builder has defined some COM types such as IUnknown in sysmac.h (is included by System.hpp) which conflicts with same types have been defined in CFPluginCOM.h, If your project includes System.hpp such as all firemonkey projects the compiler displays an error:

```
[bccosx Error] sysmac.h(287): E2238 Multiple declaration for 'IUnknown'
```

There is a sample named **DeckControl** in samples directory of DeckLink API which is a console program and you can compile it by C++Builder:

1. Create a console project and specify main.cpp as project source.
2. Select "None" as Target Framework
3. Add "OSX" Platform

The project is compiled successfuly.

And what about Fmx project (uses System.hpp) ? 
Create a wrapper unit (For example bcb_deck) put needed APIs in it. Note that do not include "DeckLinkAPI.h" in unit header, this causes same problems described above, but put it in cpp (bcb_deck.cpp), for example:

**bcb_deck.cpp:**

```
void* createDeckLinkIteratorInstance() // use camel case to prevent conflict
{
    return (void*) CreateDeckLinkIteratorInstance();
}

bool deckLinkIteratorNext(void *hDeckLinkIterator, void *hDeckLink)
{
    IDeckLinkIterator *deckLinkIterator = (IDeckLinkIterator*) hDeckLinkIterator;
    IDeckLink *deckLink = (IDeckLink*) hDeckLink;

    return deckLinkIterator->Next(&deckLink) == S_OK;
}
```

Usage:

```
#include "bcb_deck.h"
void *hDeckLinkIterator, *hDeckLink;
hDeckLinkIterator = createDeckLinkIteratorInstance();
if (hDeckLinkIterator)
{
    // Enumerate all cards in this system
    while (deckLinkIteratorNext(hDeckLinkIterator, hDeckLink))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to play with this a bit as I am seeing some things I am not familiar with, nor was I aware I can support COM as if it were a normal DLL. Note all libraries are already installed (which poses the question where I can find them) and obviously already supplied as dylib.

Comment: Can you write an example code to show how to use DeckLink Api (Cocoa)?

Comment: Sure, I added part of the code. For all code it is probably better if you download the SDK.

Comment: Well, You said "The problem is that their sample code* is written for Cocoa", It isn't, The sample code is written for C++ (Core Foundation Level), and probably is compilable by C++Builder, Am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks. Not having access to system.h proves difficult, as I need to figure out equivalents of things like string, apparently CFStringRef. However when I use this there is nothing I can do with it, the debugger does not even recognize it (says model name is 8). When I try to convert the string to char, I get an exception at CFStringGetLength() which may indicate the string is not valid.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. Is there any way you can think of a solution that still allows me to include system.h? If not, how would you use GetModelName()? It is the first function I like to get working so I can verify we're on the right track.

Comment: Have you added DeckLinkAPIDispatch.cpp to your project? you should call InitDeckLinkAPI before calling GetModelName. I dont know where can I download DeckLinkAPI.framework bundle and have not tested samples. Also you can have System.hpp in your project as described above by a Wrapper unit.

Comment: Obviously I added DeckLinkAPIDispatch to my project, without I could not even compile let alone run the program. Actually I do not think you are supposed to call InitDeckLinkAPI(), it is not public and all functions call this intrinsically, when required. I have already provided you with the download link for the API.

Comment: It works now. Although I ended up not using your code, you were very helpful in making me understand how to approach this problem and I have therefore marked your post as answer. Thank you very much for your help!